# Get False Booleans one by one from the list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a blog app in which, I have created about 10+ Booleans and I am trying to track Booleans according to the list.

I mean, Suppose, there are `5 Booleans` and all are in the `sequence`, like `[boolean_1, boolean_2, boolean_3, boolean_4, boolean_5] and they are all false.

then I am trying to get first Boolean on a page until (turning True a Boolean can take days) it is True and then boolean_2 will be seen on page boolean_1 will be removed after True.

then I am trying to get the Booleans which are `False` one by one

But I have no idea how can I filter `Booleans` which are `False` one by one.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    boolean_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boolean_2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boolean_3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boolean_4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boolean_5 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boolean_6 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
def page(request):
    listOfBooleans = [request.user.profile.boolean_1, request.user.profile.boolean_2, request.user.profile.boolean_3]

    get_first_boolean = listOfBooleans(0)

    context = {'listOfBooleans':listOfBooleans}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

I have tried by using `compress` :-

```
from itertools import compress

list_num = [1, 2, 3, 4]
profile_booleans = [request.user.profile.boolean_1, request.user.profile.boolean_2, request.user.profile.boolean_3]
list(compress(list_num, profile_booleans))
```

But this :-

- It is returning `True` instead of `False`
- I cannot access first from it, if I try by `(0)` then it is showing `'list' object is not callable`.

I have tried many times but it not working.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: What does "turning True it can days" mean?

Comment: You might be doing it in the wrong way, actually what are those boolean fields are those tags?

Comment: @mkrieger1, Sorry, It was mistake, I meant to say that a Boolean will take days to turn into `True`.

Comment: @Sumithran, `Booleans` are the model's instances.

Comment: how it could be a model instance?

Comment: Looks like you you a enum variable which goes from 0 (= no Boolean set) to n(= Boolean 1 to n set), as it seems that when a Boolean n is set it implies all Boolean n-1, n-2,   1 are true .

Comment: But how can I check through all Booleans and  get the `False` first Boolean ?